# How to install npm module from local folder?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I downloaded a package from github: [list.fuzzysearch.js](https://github.com/javve/list.fuzzysearch.js). Unzipped it to a folder

Then in my project folder, I install it as follows:
`npm install Path/to/LocalFolder/list.fuzzysearch.js-master -S`

When I bundle my project js using webpack, I got below error, which seems to miss some module required by the package I installed.

***Question 1***: Should I do a `npm install` in the downloaded package's folder first, before I install this package into my project.  i.e:  `~/local/folder/list.fuzzysearch.js-master$ npm install`

***Question 2***: when I import a module in my app.js, how do I write the path? i.e. `import module from`modulePath`, that`modulePath`, shall I just put module name (e.g. 'react'), or the path to the js file in node_module folder (e.g. 'node_module/react/dist/react.js') ?

***Question 3***: is there a way to find out all transitive dependency of a module, and install them along the way?

errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/list.fuzzysearch.js/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'classes' in /home/mypc/IdeaProject/OpenDimSum/frontend/node_modules/list.fuzzysearch.js
 @ ./~/list.fuzzysearch.js/index.js 1:14-32

ERROR in ./~/list.fuzzysearch.js/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'extend' in /home/mypc/IdeaProject/OpenDimSum/frontend/node_modules/list.fuzzysearch.js
 @ ./~/list.fuzzysearch.js/index.js 3:13-30

ERROR in ./~/list.fuzzysearch.js/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'to-string' in /home/mypc/IdeaProject/OpenDimSum/frontend/node_modules/list.fuzzysearch.js
 @ ./~/list.fuzzysearch.js/index.js 4:15-35

ERROR in ./~/list.fuzzysearch.js/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'get-by-class' in /home/mypc/IdeaProject/OpenDimSum/frontend/node_modules/list.fuzzysearch.js
 @ ./~/list.fuzzysearch.js/index.js 5:17-40
```

my app javascript:

```
require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
require ('../public/styles.css')
require ('../index.html')
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import 'list.js'
import 'list.fuzzysearch.js'
require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap')
```

Comment: Consider either installing `component` and installing this package with that package manager as suggested [here](http://www.listjs.com/docs/plugins/fuzzysearch) or use `component-webpack-plugin` [here](https://github.com/webpack/component-webpack-plugin). If you choose the first option, you would also need to use `component-as-module` [here](https://github.com/eldargab/component-as-module) to load the component as an npm module

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the script you want to use is an npm package, even though it isn't published to the npm registry. This is how you can add it to your project:

1. Add `"list.fuzzysearch": "javve/list.fuzzysearch.js"` under `dependencies` in your `package.json`
2. `npm install` as usual
3. `import fuzzysearch from 'list.fuzzysearch'`
4. ???
5. PROFIT!!!

The npm client is really flexible when it comes to where a package can be installed from. Here's the relevant [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).